# Synchronize chat over multiple windows/tabs using AppEngine Channel API

Tags: api, google-app-engine, connection, chat, channel

I am developing a chat application on top of the Google AppEngine Channel API, and one challenge is in co-ordinating/synchronizing chat when running in multiple windows/tabs (in a single browser).

In particular, if a user has a conversation open in one window/tab, and then opens a new window/tab that connects to my website, I would like for that same conversation to appear in the new window/tab (this is the functionality that Facebook chat and other websites have). I believe that this could be achieved by opening a new channel for each window that the user has open, and letting the server ensure that each channel has the most up-to-date conversation data, but I am concerned about hitting a limit (if there is one) on the number of channels allowed by the Channel API - and am also concerned about the efficiency of this approach.

So, my question is: 1) From an efficiency/effectiveness standpoint, does it makes sense to open a new channel for each window/tab for a single user? 2) Is there any kind of limit on the number of channels that I can open to a single user? 3) is there an overall limit on the number of channels that I can open? 4) is there some other more intelligent way of accomplishing my goals (perhaps using cookies or by somehow splitting data from a single channel between multiple windows/tabs)?

Thank you and kind regards
Alex

Comment: I have received some answers to this question here: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/f4c5fe18f9efa233?hl=en#

Answer (score 0):

1. Not really.
2. No.
3. http://code.google.com/intl/ro/appengine/docs/quotas.html
   Read the Channel section.
4. Yes, you could use cookies.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you should use sessionStorage, it has event listen for writing, all tabs with same origin gets the event!