# How do I code facebook-like browser notifications using AppEngine Channel API?

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

I am writing a Python AppEngine app, and need to deliver notifications to browser clients when certain backend events happen. I am using the channel API.  I have two issues: multiple page loads within the same tabs and multiple tabs.

**Multiple Page Loads**

I seem to be unable to reuse the same channel across multiple page loads.  An attempt to reconnect to the channel on the new page results in an error with code 0 and no description.  I am currently storing the channel token in the datastore and injecting the token into the page.  How can I reuse the same channel for multiple page loads within the same tab?  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958317/synchronize-chat-over-multiple-windows-tabs-using-appengine-channel-api) suggests iframes are the way. Is recoding the site with iframe my best option here?

**Tabs**

My understanding is that I need to generate a client ID for each tab the user opens. How should I generate a client ID that will be different for each opened tab?  I could just increment an ID on the server, is that the best way?

Thanks in advance,

Aaron

Answer (score 1):

I have been investigating strange channel disconnections in DEV, and it looks like Channel API is much more stable in the live environment than in the development environment.

I created a (somewhat) minimal AppEngine application that creates a channel that persists across page loads.  The app reuses a channel token from the datastore.

The code for the app is here: https://github.com/aaronlifshin/channeltest
The app itself is live at http://channeltestaaron.appspot.com/

**How to use it?**

When you go to http://channeltestaaron.appspot.com/ANYSTRING the app will create a channel and then reuse this channel for any other URLs you open of the form http://channeltestaaron.appspot.com/ANYTHING

Then you can go to http://channeltestaaron.appspot.com/broadcast to cause a message to be sent to all the other pages you've opened.

All pages have a 1-second delay to test the persistence of the channel.  This 1-second delay would cause the channel to disappear in dev.

Hope this is helpful.

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Multiple page loads: according to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960979/gae-channel-api-reconnect) you can reuse the token, however need to make sure to use it on one page at a time (it might also be a good idea to avoid page reloads and to have a single-page app that uses hash fragments).

Tabs: the most straightforward way to generate client ID is create a random string, e.g. [like this](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_string_string.js.source.html#line1043).